# Xamarin - Android Emulator does not respond

Tags: android, xamarin

When debugging my app in Xamarin, the Android Emulator immediately crashes with a 'Not Responding' message in the title bar.

Any suggestions for a work around for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: There should be an error message on the logs... It is hard to guess why it could be crashing - it would be nice if you provide further details on the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps:

1. Check that you have the most recent version of the SDK and the emulator virtual machine.
2. Check that you have enough ram memory to run an emulator.
3. Check that the emulator assigned ram memory is enough.
4. Check in Visual Studio the amount of the Java Heap Size which needs to be +1Gb
   (Android options -> Android Build -> Advanced -> Additional Options)
5. Try to factory reset your emulator from the android device manager.
6. Try using a different emulator such as GenyMotion.

Comment: All good advice, I'm sure. But steps 2, 3, and 4 need sub steps. I couldn't find anywhere in Visual Studio 2017 an option to check the "Java Heap Size". Updating the Android SDK seemed to fix this issue for me.